# Restrict the user to upload total 20 mb file

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to restrict the user to upload total `20 MB` of file at his login account in php. Is there a way without changing the setting of `php.ini` file ?

Comment: Use `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` to check for the size of the file.

Comment: Is this work for only one file? I want to allocate total 20 MB of memory space to user. In this user can use that space in one time or later.

Comment: Yes it works for one file. If you want to restrict this to multiple files, you need to track and save those file sizes (e.g. database) and check if the user wants to upload a new file

Comment: Okay, so how could I check the user file upload, if user crosses the limit, how can I restrict the upload. Can you please suggest me the code.

Comment: I provided a sample approach to this. Use PHP and HTML for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the sum of file sizes the user has already uploaded (e.g. Database table)
2. If the sum is larger than 20 MB then reject the upload at all.
3. If not, the user can upload a file which cannot be larger than difference between the sum of all file sizes of the user and your limit of 20 MB.
4. If file size is correct than log the uploaded file + size (e.g. Database)

Comment: Thank you. I am going to apply this approach.